# inject a javascript code into an Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically load a js script into an Angular template.
It worked fine, and in dev mode the source code was correct, but in production mode I got a bit wrong code.

Below is the code used to inject a js script into the template :

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var s = this.document.createElement("script");
    s.src = this.src;
    s.type = "text/javascript";

    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
  }
```

but in prod mode I got the following code :

```
<script src="//myscript.js" type="91c3f6326904bab9258c3483-text/javascript" />
```

why the `type` attribute has been changed?

The expected value is `type="text/javascript"` but got `type="91c3f6326904bab9258c3483-text/javascript"`

Comment: Try apple doing the script to document head instead

Answer (score 0):

this is called the hashing mode , when u use ng build --prod angular automatically hash all files 
to disable hashing try to use : `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`
setting --output-hashing none will create a file like main.js as opposed to main.b35d16684f410b5c0406.js which will remove cache busting.